# Can $\sum(\frac{1}{a^{n}})$ form a convergent series where $a>1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My attempt:

I am using the limit comparision test and comparing it with $\frac{1}{a}$ so $r =\lim(\frac{a}{a^n})$,where $r=0$.However the $\frac{1}{a}$ is not going to form a convergent series . So what do I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the an expansion for finite geometric series. Note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{a^n}=\frac{1-1/a^{m+1}}{1-1/a}$$
Taking limits this tends to
$$\frac{1}{1-1/a}$$
If you want to prove the geometric series formula, there are a couple of ways. One way is to note that most terms cancel in the following expression
$$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{a^n}-(1/a)\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{a^n}$$
Leaving us with
$$(1-1/a^{m+1})$$
And we simply divide to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{a^n}=\frac{1-1/a^{m+1}}{1-1/a}$$